# How can I convert multidimensional(infinity) array for one dimensional array with a limiter(30 levels)?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

The system is a multi-level marketing, then I have a array how this... but it could be with more levels(any day, maybe)...

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [id_pai] => 1
            [patente] => 1
            [nome] => Fulano
            [p_nome] => Aspirante
            [filhos] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [id_pai] => 1
            [patente] => 5
            [nome] => Cicrano
            [p_nome] => Diretor Junior
            [filhos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [id_pai] => 3
                            [patente] => 3
                            [nome] => Paulo
                            [p_nome] => Coordenador JR
                            [filhos] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                            [id_pai] => 4
                                            [patente] => 2
                                            [nome] => João
                                            [p_nome] => Consultor
                                            [filhos] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 7
                                                            [id_pai] => 6
                                                            [patente] => 2
                                                            [nome] => Pedrinho
                                                            [p_nome] => Consultor
                                                            [filhos] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [id_pai] => 3
                            [patente] => 1
                            [nome] => Pedro
                            [p_nome] => Aspirante
                            [filhos] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [id_pai] => 3
                            [patente] => 3
                            [nome] => Steven
                            [p_nome] => Coordenador JR
                            [filhos] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14
                                            [id_pai] => 9
                                            [patente] => 1
                                            [nome] => marcelo
                                            [p_nome] => Aspirante
                                            [filhos] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 15
                                            [id_pai] => 9
                                            [patente] => 1
                                            [nome] => joao da silva
                                            [p_nome] => Aspirante
                                            [filhos] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 16
                                            [id_pai] => 9
                                            [patente] => 1
                                            [nome] => claudio
                                            [p_nome] => Aspirante
                                            [filhos] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 17
                                            [id_pai] => 9
                                            [patente] => 1
                                            [nome] => carlinhos
                                            [p_nome] => Aspirante
                                            [filhos] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [id_pai] => 3
                            [patente] => 3
                            [nome] => joao da silva
                            [p_nome] => Coordenador JR
                            [filhos] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 11
                                            [id_pai] => 10
                                            [patente] => 1
                                            [nome] => joel
                                            [p_nome] => Aspirante
                                            [filhos] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 12
                                            [id_pai] => 10
                                            [patente] => 1
                                            [nome] => Paulo Roberto 
                                            [p_nome] => Aspirante
                                            [filhos] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 13
                                            [id_pai] => 10
                                            [patente] => 1
                                            [nome] => Cintia
                                            [p_nome] => Aspirante
                                            [filhos] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need take all id and push it in one directional array...
This code work in at 30 levels(could change in future).
but it is not so good for code maintenance...

```
function trataArray($array){

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

      $array2[] = array('id' => $value['id']);
      if(!empty($value['filhos'])){

        foreach ($value['filhos'] as $key2 => $value2) {

          $array2[] = array('id' => $value2['id']);
          if(!empty($value2['filhos'])){

            foreach ($value2['filhos'] as $key3 => $value3) {

              $array2[] = array('id' => $value3['id']);
              if(!empty($value3['filhos'])){

                foreach ($value3['filhos'] as $key4 => $value4) {

                  $array2[] = array('id'=> $value4['id']);
                  if(!empty($value4['filhos'])){

                    foreach ($value4['filhos'] as $key5 => $value5) {

                      $array2[] = array('id'=> $value5['id']);
                      if(!empty($value5['filhos'])){

                        foreach ($value5['filhos'] as $key6 => $value6) {

                          $array2[] = array('id'=> $value6['id']);
                          if(!empty($value6['filhos'])){

                            foreach ($value6['filhos'] as $key7 => $value7) {

                              $array2[] = array('id'=> $value7['id']);
                              if(!empty($value7['filhos'])){

                                foreach ($value7['filhos'] as $key8 => $value8) {

                                  $array2[] = array('id'=> $value8['id']);
                                  if(!empty($value8['filhos'])){

                                    foreach ($value8['filhos'] as $key9 => $value9) {

                                      $array2[] = array('id'=> $value9['id']);
                                      if(!empty($value9['filhos'])){

                                        foreach ($value9['filhos'] as $key10 => $value10) {

                                          $array2[] = array('id'=> $value10['id']);
                                          if(!empty($value10['filhos'])){

                                            foreach ($value10['filhos'] as $key11 => $value11) {

                                              $array2[] = array('id'=> $value11['id']);
                                              if(!empty($value11['filhos'])){

                                                foreach ($value11['filhos'] as $key12 => $value12) {

                                                  $array2[] = array('id' => $value12['id']);
                                                  if(!empty($value12['filhos'])){

                                                    foreach ($value12['filhos'] as $key13 => $value13) {

                                                      $array2[] = array('id' => $value13['id']);
                                                      if(!empty($value13['filhos'])){

                                                        foreach ($value13['filhos'] as $key14 => $value14) {

                                                          $array2[] = array('id'=> $value14['id']);
                                                          if(!empty($value14['filhos'])){

                                                            foreach ($value14['filhos'] as $key15 => $value15) {

                                                              $array2[] = array('id'=> $value15['id']);
                                                              if(!empty($value15['filhos'])){

                                                                foreach ($value15['filhos'] as $key16 => $value16) {

                                                                  $array2[] = array('id'=> $value16['id']);
                                                                  if(!empty($value16['filhos'])){

                                                                    foreach ($value16['filhos'] as $key17 => $value17) {

                                                                      $array2[] = array('id'=> $value17['id']);
                                                                      if(!empty($value17['filhos'])){

                                                                        foreach ($value17['filhos'] as $key18 => $value18) {

                                                                          $array2[] = array('id'=> $value18['id']);
                                                                          if(!empty($value18['filhos'])){

                                                                            foreach ($value18['filhos'] as $key19 => $value19) {

                                                                              $array2[] = array('id'=> $value19['id']);
                                                                              if(!empty($value19['filhos'])){

                                                                                foreach ($value19['filhos'] as $key20 => $value20) {

                                                                                  $array2[] = array('id'=> $value20['id']);
                                                                                  if(!empty($value20['filhos'])){

                                                                                    foreach ($value20['filhos'] as $key21 => $value21) {

                                                                                      $array2[] = array('id'=> $value21['id']);
                                                                                      if(!empty($value21['filhos'])){

                                                                                        foreach ($value21['filhos'] as $key22 => $value22) {

                                                                                          $array2[] = array('id' => $value22['id']);
                                                                                          if(!empty($value22['filhos'])){

                                                                                            foreach ($value22['filhos'] as $key23 => $value23) {

                                                                                              $array2[] = array('id' => $value23['id']);
                                                                                              if(!empty($value23['filhos'])){

                                                                                                foreach ($value23['filhos'] as $key24 => $value24) {

                                                                                                  $array2[] = array('id'=> $value24['id']);
                                                                                                  if(!empty($value24['filhos'])){

                                                                                                    foreach ($value24['filhos'] as $key25 => $value25) {

                                                                                                      $array2[] = array('id'=> $value25['id']);
                                                                                                      if(!empty($value25['filhos'])){

                                                                                                        foreach ($value25['filhos'] as $key26 => $value26) {

                                                                                                          $array2[] = array('id'=> $value26['id']);
                                                                                                          if(!empty($value26['filhos'])){

                                                                                                            foreach ($value26['filhos'] as $key27 => $value27) {

                                                                                                              $array2[] = array('id'=> $value27['id']);
                                                                                                              if(!empty($value27['filhos'])){

                                                                                                                foreach ($value27['filhos'] as $key28 => $value28) {

                                                                                                                  $array2[] = array('id'=> $value28['id']);
                                                                                                                  if(!empty($value28['filhos'])){

                                                                                                                    foreach ($value28['filhos'] as $key29 => $value29) {

                                                                                                                      $array2[] = array('id'=> $value29['id']);
                                                                                                                      if(!empty($value29['filhos'])){

                                                                                                                        foreach ($value29['filhos'] as $key30 => $value30) {

                                                                                                                          $array2[] = array('id'=> $value30['id']);
                                                                                                                          if(!empty($value30['filhos'])){

                                                                                                                            foreach ($value30['filhos'] as $key31 => $value31) {

                                                                                                                              $array2[] = array('id'=> $value31['id']);

                                                                                                                            }   
                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                          }

                                                                                                                        }   
                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                      }

                                                                                                                    }   
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                  }

                                                                                                                }   
                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                              }

                                                                                                            }   
                                                                                                                
                                                                                                          }

                                                                                                        }   
                                                                                                            
                                                                                                      }

                                                                                                    }   
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                  }

                                                                                                }

                                                                                              }         
                                                                                            }
                                                                                          }         
                                                                                        }
                                                                                      }

                                                                                    }   
                                                                                        
                                                                                  }

                                                                                }   
                                                                                    
                                                                              }

                                                                            }   
                                                                                
                                                                          }

                                                                        }   
                                                                            
                                                                      }

                                                                    }   
                                                                        
                                                                  }

                                                                }   
                                                                    
                                                              }

                                                            }   
                                                                
                                                          }

                                                        }

                                                      }         
                                                    }
                                                  }         
                                                }
                                              }

                                            }   
                                                
                                          }

                                        }   
                                            
                                      }

                                    }   
                                        
                                  }

                                }   
                                    
                              }

                            }   
                                
                          }

                        }   
                            
                      }

                    }   
                        
                  }

                }   
                    
              }         
            }
          }         
        }
      }
    }

    return $array2;

}
```

the condiction that I'm using for check if there is other array inside is
`if(!empty($value['filhos']))`
All that I need is the value key id `['id']`
in new array how this example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
        )

)
```

I think that it could be resolved with while, do while, or with any functions build in php, I tried but not got.

Comment: When you have a deeply nested structure like this, you should probably look into recursion or recursive functions to solve the problem.

Comment: The best way to do this is with a recursive function. That is a function which calls itself

Comment: Wow, the amount of inner loops here is quite amazing, have you tried recursion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get all keys of an multi level associative arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187629/can-i-get-all-keys-of-an-multi-level-associative-arrays-in-php)

Comment: About recursive function: yes i tried call the same function but I failed because that I used ```return ```

Comment: is there any build function that filter and push the value of ``` key['id'] ```
how ```$array2[] = array('id'=> $value4['id']);```